# Typography Effects not working properly on IE9

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

How can make this Typography Effects script working properly on IE? It works good on Firefox, Chrome, Safari.
http://tympanus.net/Tutorials/TypographyEffects/index6.html

Comment: IE9 doesn't support css transitions which are used in that demo

Comment: Is that have anyway can be solve this problem?

Answer (score 0):

You cannot use it because no IE below v.10 supports neither transitions nor text-shadow. You can only see it on modern browsers like Chrome, Firefox...

And also you can always check compatibility on other browsers here: http://caniuse.com/#search=text-shadow